# Best practice of single select row on table

Tags: buttons, tables, checkboxes

On the website I'm working on there are tables with multi-select row function to trigger some actions. Here is the current implementation of the table. Buttons to trigger the actions are placed on top of the table.

[image]

One thing I want to ask you, what is the best practice for single-select row on table with checkboxes? I avoid to get rid of the checkboxes since our users are not familiar with clicking directly on the rows to select them.

So far, for single select we put the action buttons at the end of each row. However, I don't think that was the best practice for this problem since it was inconsistent with button placement on tables with multi-select, and also it looks very ugly if more than one action can be done to the rows.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to support multi-select, then a checkbox is the correct UI to represent that control.

If you will not support multi-select, a radio button can offer that affordance for "single select only".

Instead of baking single-select actions into each row, you can consider putting them on top of the table as batch actions, or single actions [depending on how many row items are selected].